# How to mock django settings attributes in pytest-django

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

When using Django default unittest it's trivial to patch settings attributes (using `@override_settings` decorator for instance.)

I'd like to override several attributes of my settings for a test method. How can I go about achieving this when I'm using pytest-django?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass in `settings` as a test fixture, then modify it how you need. Here's an example from [the documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#id4):

```py
def test_with_specific_settings(settings):
    settings.USE_TZ = True
    assert settings.USE_TZ
```