# mocked settings attribute in pytest does not work with django post_save signals

Tags: python, django, pytest, signals, settings

So guys,
I am using pytest

I have checked:
[How to mock django settings attributes in pytest-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642825/how-to-mock-django-settings-attributes-in-pytest-django) and https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#id4 .
The docs mention that using following approach we can alter settings attributes:

```
def test_with_specific_settings(settings):
    settings.USE_TZ = True
    assert settings.USE_TZ
```

Thus my test class looks like:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestCase:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _setup_endpoint(self, test_user, settings) -> None:
        settings.SUSPEND_SIGNALS = True
        print(settings.SUSPEND_SIGNALS) --> returns True
        self.endpoint = endpoint setup

    def test_create(self, test_profile) -> None:
        response = self.endpoint.post(payload={})
        assert response.status_code == 401
```

test_profile triggers a signal where I check again

```
            print(settings.SUSPEND_SIGNALS) --> returns False
```

Why do I get different results?
How do I make sure that second print statement is also True?
I appreciate your help guys